# How to pass data to jquery in view from controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've a Viewbag in my controller. And i want to reach it from jquery code in view. Is it possible?
I want to check my customer's money about if it is enough for buy the product. If they don't have money enough i want to show them a sweet alert. Is it possible and if it is how can i do it?

That's my [GET] controller;

```
 public ActionResult inspect(string id, int page = 1)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("account", "product");
        }
        ViewBag.href = id;
        ViewBag.user = Session["MAIL"];
        var valuehrefid = db.TBLPRODUCT.Where(x => x.href == id).Select(y => y.ID).FirstOrDefault();
        var accounts = db.TBLACCOUNT.Where(x => x.PRODUCT == valuehrefid && x.status == true).ToList().ToPagedList(page, 10);
        return View(accounts);
    }
```

That's my [POST] controller;

```
public ActionResult buyaccount(int id)
    {
        var mail = (string)Session["MAIL"];
        var userid = db.TBLUSER.Where(x => x.MAIL == mail).Select(y => y.ID).FirstOrDefault();
        var price = db.TBLACCOUNT.Where(x => x.ID == id).Select(y => y.PRICE).FirstOrDefault();
        var user = db.TBLUSER.Find(userid);
        if (user == null || mail == null)
        {
            ViewBag.alert = "usernull";
            return RedirectToAction("login", "home");
        }
        var href = db.TBLACCOUNT.Where(x => x.ID == id).Select(y => y.TBLPRODUCT.href).FirstOrDefault();
        var customercash = user.CASH;
        if (customercash >= price)
        {
            user.CASH -= price;
            var value = db.TBLACCOUNT.Find(id);
            value.status = false;
            var product = db.TBLACCOUNT.Where(x => x.ID == id).Select(y => y.TBLPRODUCT.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            var productd = db.TBLPRODUCT.Find(urun);
            product.STOCK -= 1;
            var date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            TBLSALEACTION p = new TBLSALEACTION();
            p.CUSTOMER = userid;
            p.ACCOUNT = id;
            p.PRODUCT = product;
            p.DATE = date;
            p.PRICE = price;
            db.TBLSALEACTION.Add(p);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Uyari = "successful";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Uyari = "Customer's money is not enough to buy this.";
            int sayfa = 1;
            var valuehrefid = db.TBLPRODUCT.Where(x => x.href == href).Select(y => y.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            var accounts = db.TBLACCOUNT.Where(x => x.PRODUCT == valuehrefid && x.status == true).ToList().ToPagedList(sayfa, 10);
            return View("inspect", model: hesaplar);
        }
        return View("~/Views/accounts/inspect/" + href + ".cshtml", href);
    }
```

And that's my view

```
   @if (Session["MAIL"] != null)
        {
    <script>
                $('#TBLACCOUNT').on("click", ".btnBuy", function () {
                    var btn = $(this);
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Warning',
                        text: "Are you sure to buy this?",
                        type: 'warning',
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
                        cancelButtonText: 'No'
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.value) {
                            var id = btn.data("id");
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/accounts/buyaccount/" + id,
                                success: function (s) {
                                    if (s) {
                                btn.parent().parent().remove();
                                Swal.fire(
                                    'Information ',
                                    'You have successfully purchased!',
                                    'success'
                                );
                                    } else {
                                        Swal.fire({
                                            type: 'error',
                                            title: 'Error.',
                                            text: 'You dont have enough money.',
                                            confirmButtonText: 'Close'
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
    </script>
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this class :

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string HtmlUrl{ get; set; }
    public string HtmlBody { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

then in controller returned Json value:

```
public ActionResult buyaccount(int id)
    {
        var mail = (string)Session["MAIL"];
        var userid = db.TBLUSER.Where(x => x.MAIL == mail).Select(y => y.ID).FirstOrDefault();
        var price = db.TBLACCOUNT.Where(x => x.ID == id).Select(y => y.PRICE).FirstOrDefault();
        var user = db.TBLUSER.Find(userid);
        if (user == null || mail == null)
        {
             return Json(new JsonData()
            {
                HtmlUrl = "/home/login",
                HtmlBody = "usernull",
                Success = false,
            });
        }
        var href = db.TBLACCOUNT.Where(x => x.ID == id).Select(y => y.TBLPRODUCT.href).FirstOrDefault();
        var customercash = user.CASH;
        if (customercash >= price)
        {
            user.CASH -= price;
            var value = db.TBLACCOUNT.Find(id);
            value.status = false;
            var product = db.TBLACCOUNT.Where(x => x.ID == id).Select(y => y.TBLPRODUCT.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            var productd = db.TBLPRODUCT.Find(urun);
            product.STOCK -= 1;
            var date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            TBLSALEACTION p = new TBLSALEACTION();
            p.CUSTOMER = userid;
            p.ACCOUNT = id;
            p.PRODUCT = product;
            p.DATE = date;
            p.PRICE = price;
            db.TBLSALEACTION.Add(p);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            
            int sayfa = 1;
            var valuehrefid = db.TBLPRODUCT.Where(x => x.href == href).Select(y => y.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            var accounts = db.TBLACCOUNT.Where(x => x.PRODUCT == valuehrefid && x.status == true).ToList().ToPagedList(sayfa, 10);
            return Json(new JsonData()
            {
                HtmlUrl = "/accounts/inspect/hesaplar",
                HtmlBody = "Customer's money is not enough to buy this.",
                Success = false,
            });
        }
        
         return Json(new JsonData()
            {
                HtmlUrl = "/accounts/inspect/href",
                HtmlBody = "successful",
                Success = true,
            });
    }
```

and in script:

```
if (s.Success) {
        btn.parent().parent().remove();
        Swal.fire(
              'Information ',
              'You have successfully purchased!',
              'success'
           );
           window.location.href = s.HtmlUrl;
} else {
        Swal.fire({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Error.',
        text: s.MsgBody,
        confirmButtonText: 'Close'
    });
    window.location.href = s.HtmlUrl;
}
```

You can not transfer the program to another view with an ajax request, but you have to go back to the desired page with javascript depending on the situation.

Comment: Thanks but probably i couldn't. :S Sorry am beginner.
I updated my controller too like your sent.
But its not going to "buyaccount" action. How can i redirect it to buyaccount action with id without ajax?

Thats my view (like your sent);
https://prnt.sc/xipfqq

I updated my controller too like your sent.
Also i created a class.

Comment: okay i edited something and its working fine but when customer's dont have enough money for buy the product even so sweet alert is showing succesfull. I have a viewbag on controller. When customer's dont have money: Viewbag.Alert = "Customer's money is not enough to buy this."; When customers have money for buy the product: Viewbag.Alert = "successful"; How can i pass them to the view in script?

Comment: I just modified it. The jsonData class can return three values, it has two string values, and you can define as many variables as you want.

Comment: Thanks, u saved my life :) Have a good day